# Percentage change between 2 numbers positive or negative in php

Tags: php

Say I have 2 numbers I'd like to calculate the percentage difference along with whether it's positive or negative. I'd like the difference to be reflect the first number as the most recent.

2
5
For example this would be a decrease of 60%.

How can I do this in php

Comment: this is basic math ... 5 /2 = 2.5 = 250%, not sure where you got 60% from.

Comment: `((2 - 5) / 5) * 100)`

Comment: @Augwa (5 - 2)/5 = 60%. Omar asked for percentage difference, not a ratio. But it is still basic maths.

Comment: right, my bad. needless to say once you have the equation that's the code you need in PHP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$recent=2;
$previous=5;

$result=(($recent-$previous)/$previous);
echo "Difference is " . ($result*100) . "%.";
```

Comment: I like to keep percentages as actual percentages so I can use them...then I only multiply by 100 when I'm printing them out to be more readable.